# C# possible null reference CS8602

Tags: c#

This should be simple but I can't get ride of this null pointer warning. What can you do?
[image]

```
private static List<OrderHeader> orderHeaders = new List<OrderHeader>{...};
      /*Delete order line item from the provided OrderHeader*/
        private void DeleteOrderLine(int orderHeaderIndex, int orderLineIndex)
        {
            if (orderHeaders != null && 
                orderHeaders[orderHeaderIndex] != null && 
                orderHeaders[orderHeaderIndex].OrderLineItems != null &&
                orderHeaders[orderHeaderIndex].OrderLineItems.Count > orderLineIndex
            )
            {
                orderHeaders[orderHeaderIndex].OrderLineItems.RemoveAt(orderLineIndex);             
            } else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to delete the order line. Please try again");  
            }
        }
```

Here is second attempt.. still not working.

```
/*Delete order line item from the provided OrderHeader*/
private void DeleteOrderLine(int orderHeaderIndex, int orderLineIndex)
{
    if (orderHeaders is not null && 
        orderHeaders[orderHeaderIndex] is not null && 
        orderHeaders[orderHeaderIndex].OrderLineItems is not null &&
        orderHeaders[orderHeaderIndex].OrderLineItems.Count > orderLineIndex
    )
    {
        orderHeaders[orderHeaderIndex].OrderLineItems.RemoveAt(orderLineIndex);             
    } else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to delete the order line. Please try again");  
    }
}
```

Here's the the order Header definition

public class OrderHeader
{

```
    public enum OrderTypes
    {
        Normal = 0,
        Staff,
        Mechanical,
        Perishable
    }

    public enum OrderStatusTypes
    {
        New = 0,
        Processing,
        Complete
    }

    [Key]
    public string OrderId { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public OrderTypes OrderType { get; set; }

    public OrderStatusTypes OrderStatus { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public string CustomerName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public List<OrderLine>? OrderLineItems { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the orderLine definition

public class OrderLine
{
public int LineNumber { get; set; }

```
public string ProductCode { get; set; } = string.Empty;

public ProductTypes ProductType { get; set; } = 0;

[Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
public decimal CostPrice { get; set; }

[Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
public decimal SalePrice { get; set; }

public int Quantity { get; set; }
```

}

Comment: First, change `!= null` to `is not null`.  ([why?](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2020/11/15/c9-is-finally-here-this-is-not-about-init-only-or-records/))
Then, use `!` to tell the compiler you know this can't be null. (But in fact, in a multi thread application it might be null)

Comment: @ZoharPeled Thanks for the hint, sadly the warning is still there :(

Comment: Can you provide the definition of `orderHeaders` and the object definition of the class type that is of?

I suspect this has to do with defining nullable property objects in the class without giving them an initial value.  Specifically `OrderLineItems`.  You can probably suppress the warning by going into the csproj and changing `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` to disable.  But if you share the objects, I can help instruct how to properly initialize them so the warning goes away on its own.

Comment: @Bugs, given the additional details you've added if you WANTED to continue using the `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` you could remove the warning by changing the definition of `public List<OrderLine>? OrderLineItems { get; set; }` to be `public List<OrderLine> OrderLineItems { get; set; } = new List<OrderLine>();`  I'm not sure that's consistent with your full usage of the class though.  Or by following the above suggestion of adding the `!` in `OrderLineItems!.Count`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a common warning when using `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>`

Since you are checking that `orderHeaders[orderHeaderIndex].OrderLineItems is not null` then you can use `!` operator to indicate that it cannot be null after that check, so try:

```cs
private void DeleteOrderLine(int orderHeaderIndex, int orderLineIndex)
{
    if (orderHeaders is not null && 
        orderHeaders[orderHeaderIndex] is not null && 
        orderHeaders[orderHeaderIndex].OrderLineItems is not null &&
        orderHeaders[orderHeaderIndex].OrderLineItems!.Count > orderLineIndex
    )
    {
        orderHeaders[orderHeaderIndex].OrderLineItems!.RemoveAt(orderLineIndex);             
    } else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to delete the order line. Please try again");  
    }
}
```

Comment: This also worked. Better solution that switching off the null check in the project. Thanks for this

Answer (score 3):

I'd make life simpler by slightly changing your API and then making the analysis simpler for the compiler:

```
/*Delete order line item from the provided OrderHeader*/
private bool DeleteOrderLine(int orderHeaderIndex, int orderLineIndex)
{
    if(orderHeaders is null) return false;
    var header = orderHeaders[orderHeaderIndex];
    if(header is null) return false;
    var lineItems = header.OrderLineItems;
    if(lineItems is null || lineItems.Count <= orderLineIndex) return false;
    lineItems.RemoveAt(orderLineIndex);
    return true;
}
```

Note, it's now up to the caller to check the return value and report success to the user, log an error, etc<sup>1, 2</sup>.

This simplifies the compiler's analysis because it doesn't have to reason about, for instance, whether it's possible for the `OrderLineItems` property to be capable of modifying the `orderHeaders` collection such that the next time it's indexed into a different result will be returned.

Note also that it doesn't have to reason about that at all anyway since I only index into the collection once and the compiler knows for certain that local variables don't change their nullability after they've been checked.

---

<sup>1</sup>I.e. It's a bit of a smell that it's currently the job of this one method both to change a collection and to know the right way to interact with the users.

<sup>2</sup>In fact I'd actually probably prefer to do an additional range check on `orderHeaderIndex` and be throwing `ArgumentXxxException`s rather than returning a `bool` but that might be too much of a change to accept at this stage

Answer (score 1):

Open your .csproj file and locate the sections that has

```
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

Update for more information - disabling it will tell the compiler that you not allowing nullable types on a project scale and if there are null you will handle them